# Failed running Anaconda3 installing bash script

Tags: installation, anaconda, anaconda3

I have been trying install Anaconda3-Linux-x86_64 on my Debian machine. I followed the steps on the tutorial website (https://reurl.cc/7X4Lv9), but I faced issue when I run the bash scripts.

step 1. Download Anaconda3 bash file

```
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

step 2. Verify the integrity

```
$ sha256sum Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh 
2b9f088b2022edb474915d9f69a803d6449d5fdb4c303041f60ac4aefcc208bb  Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

step 3. Run the bash scripts (where the error occurred)

```
$ bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh

...


Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes

Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/yaochung41/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/yaochung41/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/yaochung41/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Extracting : greenlet-0.4.15-py37h7b6447c_0.conda:   7%|██                           | 22/312 [00:22<35:21,  7.32s/it]Could not remove or rename /home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/astropy-4.0-py37h7b6447c_0xah6xj0a/.nfs00000000013303cd000002a8.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
Could not remove or rename /home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/pyzmq-18.1.1-py37he6710b0_02ba8b31p/.nfs00000000013b064a000002a9.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
Could not remove or rename /home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/pip-20.0.2-py37_1fi2wa6bk/.nfs00000000013900a1000002aa.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
Could not remove or rename /home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-4.0.1-py37_0n6g9iulc/.nfs0000000001380172000002ab.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                                                                          
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 367, in _queue_management_worker
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[20962] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

I have been search solutions, and only find replies suggested me to verify the integrity which I have already done in step 2.

OS: Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you for your help.

Comment: either try running the bash command with root privileges or remove those files manually, which the error output is suggesting ```/home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/astropy-4.0-py37h7b6447c_0xah6xj0a/.nfs00000000013303cd000002a8``` and others

Comment: I am not able to use root privileges, and I also cannot find the file which the error output is suggesting. I am wondering whether it wants to rename instead of remove. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: if you are trying to delete the files by just GUI, you might not find it as some files are hidden. Try deleting them via command line. Try ```cd /home/yaochung41/anaconda3/pkgs/astropy-4.0-py37h7b6447c_0xah6xj0a/``` and then ```ls``` to see all the files and ```rm``` to delete them.

Comment: I use `ls -all` to list all files including hidden one and cannot find the files.